# Does Subscribe sound as a right name?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

So I have a `Know Your Customer` provider interface like this to estimate risks associated with a customer:

```
public interface IRiskProvider
{
    string Name { get; }
    Task<Risk[]> FindRisksAsync(Customer customer);
}
```

And I would like to be able to create an instance of it from a delegate as well as intercept all the calls to the instance:

```
public static class RiskProvider
{
    public static IRiskProvider Create(string name, Func<Customer, Task<Risk[]>> actionAsync) =>
        new Relay(name, actionAsync);

    public static IRiskProvider Subscribe(this IRiskProvider provider, Func<Customer, Risk[], Task> actionAsync) =>
        Create(provider.Name, async customer =>
        {
            var risks = await provider.FindRisksAsync(customer);
            await actionAsync(customer, risks);
            return risks;
        });

    class Relay : IRiskProvider
    {
        public Relay(string name, Func<Customer, Task<Risk[]>> actionAsync) =>
            (Name, ActionAsync) =
            (name, actionAsync);

        public string Name { get; }
        Func<Customer, Task<Risk[]>> ActionAsync { get; }
        public async Task<Risk[]> FindRisksAsync(Customer customer) =>
            await ActionAsync(customer);
    }
}
```

An example consumption code would be this `Throttler` implementing `circuit breaker decorator factory`:

```
using IHistory = IHistory<(string Provider, long UserId), (Customer Customer, Risk[] Risks)>;

[Service]
public class Throttler : IThrottler
{
    public Throttler(IHistory history) => History = history;
    IHistory History { get; }

    public IRiskProvider Throttle(IRiskProvider provider, int attempts) =>
        RiskProvider
            .Create(provider.Name, async customer =>
            {
                var calls = await History.ReadAsync((provider.Name, customer.UserId), last: attempts);
                var tooMany = calls.Length == attempts;
                return
                    tooMany ? UnknownRisk.ServiceThrottled :
                    await provider.FindRisksAsync(customer);        
            })
            .Subscribe((customer, risks) =>
                History.WriteAsync((provider.Name, customer.UserId), (customer, risks)));
}
```

Which uses a generic NoSql repository to write/read multiple values per a key:

```
public interface IHistory<TKey, TValue>
{
    Task WriteAsync(TKey key, TValue value);
    Task<(DateTime At, TValue Value)[]> ReadAsync(TKey key, int last = 1);
}
```

Does the `Subscribe` method name sounds reasonable here? Would you expect a subscription in the form of `IDisposable` being returned from it instead of subscribed instance suitable for chaining? What would be a better name instead of `Subscribe` for such an API to intercept all the calls?

It just looks like some mix between `IEnumerable` and `IObservable` for me. Would some simple `ForEach` be better?

Comment: Please help me clarify what do you really want to achieve!? `IEnumerable` + `ForEach` is **pull based** mechanism. On the other hand the `IObservable` + `Subscribe` is a **push based** approach. Which one do you want to support?

Comment: @PeterCsala I think it is a middle ground. `Subscribe` executes *push based* callback when *pull based* `FindRiskAsync` is become invoked...

Comment: @DimitryNogin Do I understand correctly that you retrieve data then you pass that to a consumer defined function and finally you return with the amended data?

Comment: @PeterCsala There are three fundamental things you could do: create an instance, intercept the call, or intercept and replace the result. I support create and intercept (for logging purposes) only here.

Comment: @DimitryNogin In my opinion if you want to only allow interception than I would recommend to use immutable structures.Currently the `risks` is amendable in the callback. If you would pass an `ImmutableArray` rather than a simple `Array` then the callback would not be able to modify the `risks`. I would also consider to make the callback optional, because not each and every consumer would like to intercept.

Comment: @PeterCsala What could be more optional than skipping the `Subscribe` call?

Comment: @DmitiryNogin Yep, that's a valid point, because you are providing a fluent API. :D By revisiting your code I can see that call of the `FindRiskAsync` is the done inside the delegate of the `Create` method. So, if I call the `Subscribe` as well then I will call the `FindRiskAsync` twice, right?

Comment: @PeterCsala Nope, it just chains. Try to play with the code, it is a useful pattern to know.